# How can I do a bulk search to see if any of my photographs are used online without my permission?

Tags: images, search-engine, internet, search

Can someone recommend a service or software that will help to search published photos online?

I tried to do this with Google Image search but it requires a lot of time to upload images one by one. I'd like to check several photos at once, not one by one.

Comment: Search with a smaller version of your images, say 640x480, will reduce your upload time - any search will either require your photo(s) to be uploaded or **every** photo on the net to be downloaded, *guess which is quicker*!

Comment: Bear in mind that Google image search and tineye.com (which has a good API, if you are a programmer) will always respect robots.txt, which means, in my experience, that you can't search FaceBook, for instance

Comment: @SteveBarnes - thanks for these ideas!